# How to setup data layer variables values of a link click in Google Analytics Dashboard

Tags: google-analytics

I need understand that is there any way from which I can see my custom data layer variables values in Google Analytics dashboard.

What I have set on website page on link click: 
On 4th object you can that I have pushing a variable name "role-name" on link click.
I just want this value on Google Analytics Dashboard. (See below Screenshot)

[image]
Please help me how I can see this Google Analytics dashboard later I need to push more than one custom variable value too.

Waiting for kind responses.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You must send that value together with a google analytics hit (for example a custom dimension with pageview tag).

Comment: What I have did:
1 - Created a CD in GA 
2 - Created a tag, variable and trigger in GTM dashboard
3 - In my tag, I have provided custom dimension index to 1 (I have only one CD in GA)
4 - In place of Dimension Value, I have provided my newly created variable name 
{{GT - RoleDetails Variable}}
5 - In my variable in Data Layer Variable Name, I have given my key name as I written in my push event JS.

6 - After setting all above things, I am not able to see the result in GA.

Please guide me.